# how to show "no match found" in typehead in angular ui?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

What I want to do is this: when a user starts typing in the typehead input and no matches are found it should show a message saying "no match found".

Below is the code and a plunker:

HTML

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
  <a>
      <img ng-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/{{match.model.flag}}" width="16">
      <span ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
  </a>
</script>

<div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

    <h4>Custom templates for results</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{customSelected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control" typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-min-length="0">

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var _selected;

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
  // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously
  $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.data.results.map(function(item){
        return item.formatted_address;
      });
    });
  };

  $scope.ngModelOptionsSelected = function(value) {
    if (arguments.length) {
      _selected = value;
    } else {
      return _selected;
    }
  };

  $scope.modelOptions = {
    debounce: {
      default: 500,
      blur: 250
    },
    getterSetter: true
  };

  $scope.statesWithFlags = [{'name':'Alabama','flag':'5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/45px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png'},{'name':'Alaska','flag':'e/e6/Flag_of_Alaska.svg/43px-Flag_of_Alaska.svg.png'},{'name':'Arizona','flag':'9/9d/Flag_of_Arizona.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arizona.svg.png'},{'name':'Arkansas','flag':'9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arkansas.svg.png'},{'name':'California','flag':'0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/45px-Flag_of_California.svg.png'},{'name':'Colorado','flag':'4/46/Flag_of_Colorado.svg/45px-Flag_of_Colorado.svg.png'},{'name':'Connecticut','flag':'9/96/Flag_of_Connecticut.svg/39px-Flag_of_Connecticut.svg.png'},{'name':'Delaware','flag':'c/c6/Flag_of_Delaware.svg/45px-Flag_of_Delaware.svg.png'},{'name':'Florida','flag':'f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg/45px-Flag_of_Florida.svg.png'},{'name':'Georgia','flag':'5/54/Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg.png'},{'name':'Hawaii','flag':'e/ef/Flag_of_Hawaii.svg/46px-Flag_of_Hawaii.svg.png'},{'name':'Idaho','flag':'a/a4/Flag_of_Idaho.svg/38px-Flag_of_Idaho.svg.png'},{'name':'Illinois','flag':'0/01/Flag_of_Illinois.svg/46px-Flag_of_Illinois.svg.png'},{'name':'Indiana','flag':'a/ac/Flag_of_Indiana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Indiana.svg.png'},{'name':'Iowa','flag':'a/aa/Flag_of_Iowa.svg/44px-Flag_of_Iowa.svg.png'},{'name':'Kansas','flag':'d/da/Flag_of_Kansas.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kansas.svg.png'},{'name':'Kentucky','flag':'8/8d/Flag_of_Kentucky.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kentucky.svg.png'},{'name':'Louisiana','flag':'e/e0/Flag_of_Louisiana.svg/46px-Flag_of_Louisiana.svg.png'},{'name':'Maine','flag':'3/35/Flag_of_Maine.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maine.svg.png'},{'name':'Maryland','flag':'a/a0/Flag_of_Maryland.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maryland.svg.png'},{'name':'Massachusetts','flag':'f/f2/Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg/46px-Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg.png'},{'name':'Michigan','flag':'b/b5/Flag_of_Michigan.svg/45px-Flag_of_Michigan.svg.png'},{'name':'Minnesota','flag':'b/b9/Flag_of_Minnesota.svg/46px-Flag_of_Minnesota.svg.png'},{'name':'Mississippi','flag':'4/42/Flag_of_Mississippi.svg/45px-Flag_of_Mississippi.svg.png'},{'name':'Missouri','flag':'5/5a/Flag_of_Missouri.svg/46px-Flag_of_Missouri.svg.png'},{'name':'Montana','flag':'c/cb/Flag_of_Montana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Montana.svg.png'},{'name':'Nebraska','flag':'4/4d/Flag_of_Nebraska.svg/46px-Flag_of_Nebraska.svg.png'},{'name':'Nevada','flag':'f/f1/Flag_of_Nevada.svg/45px-Flag_of_Nevada.svg.png'},{'name':'New Hampshire','flag':'2/28/Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg.png'},{'name':'New Jersey','flag':'9/92/Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg.png'},{'name':'New Mexico','flag':'c/c3/Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg.png'},{'name':'New York','flag':'1/1a/Flag_of_New_York.svg/46px-Flag_of_New_York.svg.png'},{'name':'North Carolina','flag':'b/bb/Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg.png'},{'name':'North Dakota','flag':'e/ee/Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg/38px-Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg.png'},{'name':'Ohio','flag':'4/4c/Flag_of_Ohio.svg/46px-Flag_of_Ohio.svg.png'},{'name':'Oklahoma','flag':'6/6e/Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg/45px-Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg.png'},{'name':'Oregon','flag':'b/b9/Flag_of_Oregon.svg/46px-Flag_of_Oregon.svg.png'},{'name':'Pennsylvania','flag':'f/f7/Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg/45px-Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg.png'},{'name':'Rhode Island','flag':'f/f3/Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg/32px-Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg.png'},{'name':'South Carolina','flag':'6/69/Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg.png'},{'name':'South Dakota','flag':'1/1a/Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg/46px-Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg.png'},{'name':'Tennessee','flag':'9/9e/Flag_of_Tennessee.svg/46px-Flag_of_Tennessee.svg.png'},{'name':'Texas','flag':'f/f7/Flag_of_Texas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Texas.svg.png'},{'name':'Utah','flag':'f/f6/Flag_of_Utah.svg/45px-Flag_of_Utah.svg.png'},{'name':'Vermont','flag':'4/49/Flag_of_Vermont.svg/46px-Flag_of_Vermont.svg.png'},{'name':'Virginia','flag':'4/47/Flag_of_Virginia.svg/44px-Flag_of_Virginia.svg.png'},{'name':'Washington','flag':'5/54/Flag_of_Washington.svg/46px-Flag_of_Washington.svg.png'},{'name':'West Virginia','flag':'2/22/Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg/46px-Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg.png'},{'name':'Wisconsin','flag':'2/22/Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg/45px-Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg.png'},{'name':'Wyoming','flag':'b/bc/Flag_of_Wyoming.svg/43px-Flag_of_Wyoming.svg.png'}];
});
```

Here is the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/4ITTjdo8MwXmwmzR8sJU?p=preview) in plunker.

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeahead-no-results`. Add the following to your input

```
typeahead-no-results="noResults"
```

Then add the following, or similar, below.

```
<div ng-show="noResults">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Match Found
</div>
```

I've amended your Plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/RCUkVId8FwhaF6iObhql?p=preview)

Comment: plus the doc here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead. And demo code: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/docs/demo.html#L61-L65